# List View Change

Tags: sharepoint

I know that a list permission can be changed. But it there a way to completely omit a user to see a list. Example - USer A can see Event List but User B cannot see it. Can this be done? Your suggestions will be helpful. Thanks,

Comment: Isn't this the same thing as changing permissions on the list?

Answer (score 1):

If the list has unique permissions (i.e. not set to inherit from it's parent) then the permissions can be configured to only allow groups which do not include User B.

One this is done, User B will not even see the list - they will be unaware that it exists.

If User A forwards User B a direct link to the list, User B will be instead be redirected to the AccessDenied.aspx page.

Comment: Hey Brian,

Does this mean that when I create the site I select give unique permissions instead of inherit permissions from parent site. However, I have already inherited though I am thinking can this be done programmatically.

Example - If list dont have unique permissions - break inheritance and then list.hide() or something like that..

Any thoughts...?

Comment: Not exactly - a list belonging to a unique permissions site will then inherit its permissions from that child site. You need to break the inheritance at the list level too.  

Conversely, the child site can inherit its parent's permissions, but the list under it can still have unique permissions if you choose.

Also, you can break the inheritance at any time - on creation or later (and re-establish inheritance if need be).

Just be wary of too many unique permissions on sites/lists/documents/items etc as it can become a nightmare to manage.